# CSP headers are not set in Django in Apache server how to rectify

Tags: django-settings, security-testing, content-security-policy

In Django I m trying set the CSP headers but it is not setting.
I tried with various methods but it doesn't works.
I used to code in settings.py but CSP headers not set in Django.

CSP_REPORT_URI = example.com
CSP_NONCE_SCRIPT = False  # True if you want to use it

CSP_NONCE_STYLE = False  # True if you want to use it

CSP_FLAG_STRICT = False  # True to include strict-dynamic in CSP

CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'self'",)

CSP_OBJECT_SRC = ("'none'",)

CSP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS = True

CSP_INCLUDE_NONCE_IN = ('script-src', )

CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = ("'self'", "cdn.example.com" )

CSP_STYLE_SRC = ("'self'","stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com" )

CSP_FONT_SRC = ("'self'", "fonts.example.com", )

CSP_IMG_SRC = ("'self'", "example.com", "www.example.com")

CSP_CONNECT_SRC = ("'self'", "example.com", "www.example.com")

CSP_FRAME_SRC = ("'none'",)

CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ("'self'", )

CSP_FORM_ACTION = ("'self'", )

CSP_MANIFEST_SRC = ("'self'", )

CSP_WORKER_SRC = ("'self'", )

CSP_MEDIA_SRC = ("'self'", )